# How to pass different lines of code based on multiple arguments in R?

Tags: r

Opening up a new session due to too many edits.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                         value = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))
```

And I would like to pass something like this using an `if else` statement, but it does not work because `the condition has length >1`:

```
if (df$ID =="A"| df$ID=="B"){
df$nat[df$value %in% c(1,2)] <- 1
df$hrv[df$value %in% c(3)] <- 1}
else {
df$nat[df$value %in% c(1)] <- 1
df$hrv[df$value %in% c(2,3)] <- 1}
```

I know I could split the dataset and do seperate calcululations and bind it together again, but is there a simpler approach, something like I suggested above?

So I would end up with something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                         value = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                         nat = c(1,1,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,NA),
                         hrv = c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1,1))
```

Comment: Check your data sets. They are not reproducible

Comment: We need ifelse(), not if(){}else(){}

Comment: Can you please check your code before posting, thanks.

Comment: My bad, coppied in the wrong code, works now

Comment: @zx8754 But how would I use it to create two new rows in example ```td$nat``` and ```td$hrv``` by using ```%in%``` based on another column?

Comment: @Maël edited, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You can use variations of `ifelse`, `if_else` or `case_when` statements. Here is one using `case_when` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(isAB = ID %in% c("A", "B"), 
         nat = case_when((isAB & value %in% c(1, 2))|(!isAB & value %in% 1) ~ 1),
         hrv = case_when((isAB & value %in% 3)|(!isAB & value %in% c(2, 3)) ~ 1))

#  ID value  isAB nat hrv
#1  A     1  TRUE   1  NA
#2  A     2  TRUE   1  NA
#3  A     3  TRUE  NA   1
#4  B     1  TRUE   1  NA
#5  B     2  TRUE   1  NA
#6  B     3  TRUE  NA   1
#7  C     1 FALSE   1  NA
#8  C     2 FALSE  NA   1
#9  C     3 FALSE  NA   1
```

`isAB` is a temporary column created to avoid doing `ID %in% c("A", "B")` multiple times. You can drop it at the end if it is not needed.

We have combined two conditions using OR (`|`).

Comment: When applying it to my dataframe I am getting an error that ```nat``` should be length 1 and not length of my df....